# spring boot could not find bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

it is my pom.xml after running spring project i got error

i tried this thongs but not done this

If you've tried all the steps and are still encountering the issue, let's explore a few additional troubleshooting steps:

1. **Check Component Scanning**: Ensure that your XML configuration or Java configuration includes the package where your `UserRepository` implementation resides. If you're using component scanning, make sure that the package containing the repository is scanned by Spring.

2. **Check Implementation Class**: Double-check that your `UserRepository` interface has an appropriate implementation class that is correctly annotated with `@Repository`.

3. **Verify Bean Name**: If you're explicitly defining the bean in XML configuration, make sure that the bean name matches the name expected by the component that's trying to autowire it. You can use the `id` attribute in the `<bean>` definition to specify the bean name.

4. **Check for Multiple Contexts**: Ensure that there is no accidental creation of multiple application contexts that might cause beans not to be visible where they're needed. This can happen if you're using multiple XML configuration files or if you're mixing XML configuration with Java configuration.

5. **Review Dependency Injection**: Check if there are any custom qualifiers or other annotations on the `UserRepository` dependency injection point (`CustomUserDetailsService`). These annotations could affect the bean resolution process.

6. **Debugging**: If possible, set breakpoints or add logging statements to trace the bean creation process. This can help identify if the bean is being created and if there are any issues during initialization.

7. **Dependency Versions**: Ensure that all dependencies in your project, especially Spring-related dependencies, are compatible with each other. Sometimes, conflicts between different versions of Spring dependencies can cause bean creation issues.

8. **Consult Community/Documentation**: If none of the above steps resolve the issue, consider reaching out to the Spring community forums or consulting the official Spring documentation for troubleshooting tips specific to your scenario.

By carefully reviewing these aspects, you should be able to pinpoint the issue causing the `UserRepository` bean not to be found in your Spring application context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version> <!-- or the appropriate version -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

          <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
     </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <version>1.18.20</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Maven -->
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
     </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
             <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
             <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0</version> <!-- Use the latest version here -->
              </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
/Desktop/beckend/java_back$  /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:42975 @/tmp/cp_2akgesudot11bi0kws3dn676g.argfile com.example.demo.DemoApplication 
Error: could not open `/tmp/cp_2akgesudot11bi0kws3dn676g.argfile'
vansh@satellite:~/Desktop/beckend/java_back$  cd /home/vansh/Desktop/beckend/java_back/demo ; /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:46277 @/tmp/cp_ej0uoxrfv0buwdyy0i6h7o7rl.argfile com.example.demo.DemoApplication 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.3)

2024-03-11T16:16:05.139+05:30  INFO 237523 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 21.0.2 with PID 237523 (/home/vansh/Desktop/beckend/java_back/demo/target/classes started by vansh in /home/vansh/Desktop/beckend/java_back/demo)
2024-03-11T16:16:05.144+05:30  INFO 237523 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-11T16:16:07.100+05:30  WARN 237523 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurity': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService' defined in file [/home/vansh/Desktop/beckend/java_back/demo/target/classes/com/example/demo/security/CustomUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2024-03-11T16:16:07.143+05:30  INFO 237523 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-11T16:16:07.237+05:30 ERROR 237523 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.security.CustomUserDetailsService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.

vansh@satellite:~/Desktop/beckend/java_back/demo$
```

Comment: what makes you think your pom causes this? Did you define such a bean?

Comment: Fix your dependencies, they are a mess. Remove the `spring-data-jpa` dependency, remove the `persistence-api` dependency, remove the `jakarta-validation-api` one and use `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead. Remove `jakarta.servlet-api` that is pulled in (or not) from starters, if it isn't you don't need it. So you didn't try all those things you said you did. You are probably "following a tutorial" and decided to use a newer version of the framework instead of the one from the tutorial instead.